# Python: Unexpected behavior using contextmanager on class method

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager

I'm trying to use the with..as contruct in Python to make writing "reversible computing" code easier. However, using `@contextmanager` on a class method seems to change the default initialization of future class instances. Python 2.6 and 3.1 have the same behavior. Here is a simple example exhibiting this behavior:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import contextlib

class SymList:
    def __init__(self, L=[]):
        self.L = L

    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def SymAdd(self, a):
        self.L.append(a)
        yield
        self.L.append(a)

SL = SymList()
with SL.SymAdd(3):
    SL.L.append(5)
print(SL.L) # Expect and see [3, 5, 3]
SL2 = SymList()
print(SL2.L) # Expect [] and see [3, 5, 3]
```

- Why isn't `SL2` a fresh instance of `SymList`?
- How is the `SL2.L` data member referring to the `SL.L` data member?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This behavior is due to how [mutable default arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/505154) work in Python.

Try changing `SymList.__init__()` to the following:

```
    def __init__(self, L=None):
        if L is None:
             self.L = []
        else:
             self.L = L
```

As you modify `self.L` in one instance you are also modifying the `L` that is passed into `SymList.__init__()`, so the result with your code is that all instances would share the same `L` attribute when the instance is first initialized.

Comment: That makes sense. I was blinded thinking it was something fancier with decorators. Thanks!